# Nginx redirect to https need page refresh

Tags: http, redirect, nginx, https

I have look through tutorials over the Internet to redirect http -> https.
I have got it worked out, but it doesn't work 100% correctly

**My environment on CentOS 6.5 (right now everything is set in 1 server as it is in development mode):**

1.) 1 nginx (v 1.8.0) load balancer (running on port 443 and 80)

2.) 2 node.js express.js web servers (running on port 3000)

3.) 1 mongodb database (running on port 27017)

**What I got so far**

I am trying to redirect my user from http to https on a load balancer.

I want my node.js to render "Hello from nodes" ( it is set up )

**What went wrong**

When I enter https://my.domain.com , it render "Hello from nodes" ( work correctly )

But when I enter http://my.domain.com , it render "Welcome to nginx"; however, when I refresh the browser it render "Hello from nodes"

It seems like I have to refresh my browser in order to be redirected to https.

I want it to redirect to https right after I enter http://my.domain.com without needs of page refresh

Thank you very much :)

**Here is my code in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf on nginx v1.8.0**

**I got this code from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-with-ssl-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-jenkins**

```
server {
  listen       443 ssl;
  server_name  localhost;

  ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/ssl/ffml-cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/ffml-key.pem;

  ssl on;
  ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;


  location / {

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
      proxy_pass          http://localhost:3000;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;

      proxy_redirect      http://localhost:3000;

  }
}

server {
  listen         80;
  return         301 https://$host$request_uri?;

}
```

Comment: You don't need proxy_redirect, try with curl as your browser's cache might be showing cached items.

Comment: @itpp13 Thanks, it works. 

I got it worked after I clear all the browser cache.